# Behavior of return and echo in php

Tags: php

I am confused about how the program is working; the code should print `A, bB`  but it is showing `bA,B`

```
class SampleClass {
    public $a = "A";
    protected $b = array ("a" => "A", "b" => "B", "c" => "C");

    public function __get($v){
        echo "$v";
        return $this->b[$v];
    }
}

$m = new SampleClass();

echo $m->a . ", " . $m->b;
```

Comment: Why are you think, that expected output should be 'A, bB'?

Comment: Stranger for me is the fact that **echo $m->b** returns bB and **echo $m->a** returns A and not aA

Comment: $a is a public var so it does not need to use the __get method.

Comment: Thank you for providing a new question to to ask candidates who apply for a job :) 

Really nice question!

Comment: Just to really make it interesting: You can separate clauses in the `echo` statement with a  comma. i.e. `echo $m->a, ', ', $m->b;` - this returns the output you expect of: _`A, bB`_. The clue is that here, each clause, is evaluated separately. When you use an 'operator', such as `concatenation`, then it needs to be fully evaluated first. The output order of 'nested' `echo` statements, while evaluating, is 'interesting'. Please note: `echo` is not a function but a language construct.

Comment: @Patrick, as an interview question - difference between comma and fullstops, as an operator, in an `echo` statement?

Comment: @RyanVincent thats actually new to me! Nice indeed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This makes perfect sense really. Let's think about the execution order:

Before PHP can ECHO your requested string, it must evaluate it first (i.e. the `$m->a . ", " . $m->b` part)

So at this point, the parser tries to resolve $m->a and $m->b, it resolves the first, but the 2nd fails, so we go to the magic method.

The magic method echos something (the first `b), and then resolves itself to B.

Now, we need to finish what we started (the original echo).

So what do we have?

1. resolve the $m->b(echo in b in the process).
2. echo "A,B"

combine it all together?

bA,B

Comment: in other words, the string being built by the `echo $m->a ...` stuff can't be output until the string is completed, so its contents actually echo AFTER the echo inside the method.

Comment: @Dudling don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is odd isn't it but it isn't doing what you think it is doing.

Running this code does something different.

```
class SampleClass {
    public $aaa = "A";
    protected $b = array ("a"=> "A", "b" => "B", "c" => "C");

    public function __get($v){
        echo "$v";
        return $this->b[$v];
    }
}


$m = new SampleClass();

echo "[" . $m->a. ", ". $m->b. ", ". $m->c . "]";
```

Output is:

`abc[A, B, C]`

Your original __get does not get called when you do $m->a since there is a variable 'a' anyhow. It is only called as a last resort so you should write your own specific 'getter' function instead.